# How to stream video in the GUI using PyQt5?

Tags: ffmpeg, pyqt5

I am a newbie with Python as well as ffmpeg. Once the webcam is assigned to the Pine, the video gets stored in the /mnt/hls directory. The video from this directory needs to be displayed on the Front End which was designed using QtDesigner and the wiring is done using PyQt5. The video needs to be displayed when a button is clicked by the user in the OpenGLWidget.
The command line for the video stream is `"Ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay [HLS playlist]"`, which can be run using `os.system()`. My issue is with getting the video displayed in the OpenGLWidget. Could someone help me through this or direct me to another similar question or a different link? Thank you.